# Modelling a series of elements of the same entity in JPA (one-to-one relation)

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, relational-database, entity-relationship

I created an entity/table for a book, and I want to achieve that each element can reference another book to create a series.

I came up with this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer bookId;

    @Lob
    private String text;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book previousPart;


}
```

However, the attribute `previousPart` is not seen as a column in my Database, while the others are. Is there a different annotation I have to use or is this the wrong way to model a relationship like this? Or do I have to use the type `Integer` instead of `Book` directly (I thought this was what the framework does internally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private Book previousPart;
```

In your code you defined the `book_id` field as the join-column, which is an already existing column (the id itself), so actually you linked all entries to themselves.